# Delay before recursive function call

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a delay before every recursive function call. Currently, it's returning `undefined`. The problem might be the scope of the recursive call (inside settimeout and then).
I tried it like this:

```
    function delay(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, ms)
        });
    } 

    const checkIfListElementIsRendered = (className) => {
        delay(10).then(function (res) {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0]) {
                return true;
            }
            return checkIfListElementIsRendered(className);
        })
    }
```

And this:

```
    const checkIfListElementIsRendered = (className) => {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0]) {
            return true;
        }
            
        setTimeout(() => {
            return checkIfListElementIsRendered(className);
        }, 10);   
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't return anything so nothing is returned. Mark function as async and add await

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn `checkIfListElementIsRendered` to `async/await` syntax, and `await` the `delay` and `checkIfListElementIsRendered` methods, Also instead return `true` turn it to `promise` to be always return a `promise`.

When you call `checkIfListElementIsRendered` method outside, you need to resolve it with `await` or `then` callback.

```
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    });
} 

const checkIfListElementIsRendered = async (className) => {
   await delay(10)
   if (document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0]) {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
   }
   return await checkIfListElementIsRendered(className);
}
```